# Swift string encoding

Tags: ios, swift

My string has **&** and I want to replace it with the percentage encoding (**%26**). This is just an example. There can be any escape character.
I tried this but it is not replacing **&** with **%26** :

```
password.text?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

Comment: Its an allowed character in the url, if you need to encode that then have to create your own character set or replace manually

Comment: May be this will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/43054388/6433023

Answer (score 0):

How about this short string extension:

```
extension String
{
    func encode(_ chars: String) -> String
    {
        let forbidden = CharacterSet(charactersIn: chars)
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: forbidden.inverted) ?? self
    }
}

print("I can't read ENCODED text".encode("CDENO"))
// will print: I can't read %45%4E%43%4F%44%45%44 text

print("Command & Conquer".encode("&"))
// will print: Command %26 Conquer
```