# Decode plus sign (+) to space in URLComponent

Tags: swift, foundation

I have a query item in a URL: `q=Yellowstone+national+park`. When using `URLComponents` to decode and extract the query value using the following, I get `Yellowstone+national+park` instead of `Yellowstone national park`.

```
let someURL = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/?q=Yellowstone+national+park")!
let components = URLComponents(url: someURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)

let keyword = components?.queryItems?.first(where: { (queryItem) -> Bool in
        return queryItem.name == "q"
    })?.value ?? "Keyword is empty"
```

I found `URLComponents` work fine with percent-encoded queries:

> `q=%E8%BF%87%E5%B1%B1%E8%BD%A6` --> `过山车`
>
> `q=Yellowstone+national+park`   --> `Yellowstone+national+park`

Is there anyway `URLComponents` can automatically convert `+` to space  ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

from Apple Documentation:

> RFC 3986 specifies which characters must be percent-encoded in the
>   query component of a URL, but not how those characters should be
>   interpreted. The use of delimited key-value pairs is a common
>   convention, but isn't standardized by a specification. Therefore, you
>   may encounter interoperability problems with other implementations
>   that follow this convention.
>
> One notable example of potential interoperability problems is how the
>   plus sign (+) character is handled:
>
> According to RFC 3986, the plus sign is a valid character within a
>   query, and doesn't need to be percent-encoded. However, according to
>   the W3C recommendations for URI addressing, the plus sign is reserved
>   as shorthand notation for a space within a query string (for example,
>   ?greeting=hello+world).
>
> If a URL query component contains a date formatted according to RFC
>   3339 with a plus sign in the timezone offset (for example,
>   2013-12-31T14:00:00+00:00), interpreting the plus sign as a space
>   results in an invalid time format. RFC 3339 specifies how dates should
>   be formatted, but doesn't advise whether the plus sign must be
>   percent-encoded in a URL. **Depending on the implementation receiving
>   this URL, you may need to preemptively percent-encode the plus sign
>   character.**

Don't know the reason for downvote the answer:

similar issue described here: [Encode '+' using URLComponents in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052657/encode-using-urlcomponents-in-swift)